# Função jQuery anônima passando parâmetros ao chama-la

Tags: javascript, jquery

É possível passar parâmetros em um função jQuery para que eu possa utiliza-la vários vezes com vários elementos? Preciso deixa-la com elementos indeterminados e passa-los como parâmetros determinando-os ao chamar a função, assim como é feito da forma tradicional.

Exemplo: Tenho a função com elementos determinados:

```
$('button').click(function() {
    $el = $(this).closest('[id]').attr('id');
    $('#s').html($el);
});
```

e preciso dela mais ou menos assim, com elementos indeterminados:

```js
function teste($x){
        $el = $(this).closest('[id]').attr('id');
        $('#s').html($el);
}
```

para depois chama-la passando o parâmetro:

```html
<button onclick="teste('meuID');">Pronto</button>
```

Alguém tem ideia de como executar essa façanha?

Comment: A tua lógica está certa, tiveste algum erro ou dificuldade a implementar?

Comment: Sergio, chamar um script jquery de forma js tradicional não funciona. Veja: https://jsfiddle.net/g83v0vnr/20/

Comment: Ah, percebi. Tens de fazer assim: https://jsfiddle.net/g83v0vnr/21/

Comment: Perfeito!! Sergio coloque a solução como resposta para eu votar. Valeuuuu!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O problema é que `$('button').click(function() {` passa o elemento clicado como contexto de execução dessa função anónima. Ou seja o `this` é o `button` clicado.

Quando usas uma função nomeada, passando inline no HTML aí o contexto de execução é outro, ie `window`. Mas podes usar `onclick="teste('#meuID', this);"` e aí vai ser passada uma referência do elemento clicado como argumento da função. E depois dentro da função podes fazer assim:

```
function teste($x, self) {
    $el = $(self).closest('[id]').attr('id');
    $($x).html($el);
}
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/g83v0vnr/21/